# Show admin action with out login in

Tags: admin, module, layout, login

I need to show a page with out having the admin user log in.  They need to move from

http://local.mage.dev/index.php/admin/

http://local.mage.dev/index.php/admin/wsu/requestaccess/

With out loggin in.  As of right now, I just see the login page when I go to the requestaccess action URL.  I need to be able to show a form.  I have not yet found a way to say it's ok show this stuff yet. This is what I have in my controller, and althou I get to the url as I needed to, the page should be showing the login form.

app\code\local\Wsu\Adminldap\controllers\Adminhtml\WsuController.php

```
<?php
class Wsu_Adminldap_Adminhtml_WsuController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    /**
     * Forgot administrator password action
     * Request Access 
     */
    public function requestaccessAction() {
        echo "test";
        die();
    }

    /**
     * Check if user has permissions to access this controller
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _isAllowed(){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't extend from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` extend from `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` then there is no check for login.

### Alternative:

Extend from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` and overwrite `\Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::preDispatch()` remove the

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $_isValidFormKey = $this->_validateFormKey();
            $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.');
        } elseif (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
            $_isValidSecretKey = $this->_validateSecretKey();
            $_keyErrorMsg = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Point. Everything said :-)

Comment: That has not been proving as duh as I would wish.  This is the login form, and it comes from the Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action  and working with this from the front has proven to be just as much of a pain.  I agree it's seemingly duh choice, and what I did first before I even came here, but I need to come in the same way the forgot password form comes in.  I need theme and layout.  as of yet I have not be able to just pull the admin theme to the front.  still working on it, but this has not proven to bypass, and the original question still stands.  I have to imagine there is a way to do it.

Comment: added alternative